# Error in different methods of executing stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, exec

I noticed that a stored procedure can be executed as

```
EXEC myProc;
```

as well as

```
myProc;
```

assuming `myProc` is a stored procedure with no parameters.

Things work fine when I try to execute them one by one. But executing them together

```
EXEC myProc;
myProc;
```

I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near 'myProc'.

What seems to be the error here? I tried with and without `;`. Without `;`

```
EXEC myProc
myProc
```

it will think I am trying to pass second `myProc` as param to the first procedure `myProc` and I get error

> Msg 8146, Level 16, State 1, Procedure myProc, Line 0
>   Procedure myProchas no parameters and arguments were supplied.

More information:

```
myProc;
EXEC myProc;
```

and

```
myProc
EXEC myProc
```

will execute, although the editor will signal a syntax error at the first `myProc` call (`incorrect syntax near myProc`) which will go away if I put a `GO` before it. Besides, it will not try to guess that the second `EXEC myProc` has anything to do as parameters for the first `myProc` call, which I suppose because `EXEC` helps remove the ambiguity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the SQL Server Books Online reference (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx):

> You do not have to specify the EXECUTE keyword when executing modules
>   if the statement is the first one in a batch.

**EDIT:**

Let's examine the individual batches in your question.

This batch succeeds:

```
EXEC myProc;
```

This batch succeeds because it is the first statement in the batch so the `EXECUTE` keyword is optional:

```
myProc;
```

This batch results in a syntax error because the second statement in the batch is missing the `EXECUTE` keyword; `EXECUTE` may only omitted only from the first statement.  Even with the syntax error, the proper use of statement terminators at least helps the T-SQL parser understand your intent.

```
EXEC myProc;
myProc;
```

This batch fails with a supplied parameter error.  The first statement is missing the statement terminator and the second statement is missing the `EXECUTE` keyword.  The combination of these errors cause the second proc name to be interpreted as a parameter to the first and only execute statement in the batch:

```
EXEC myProc
myProc
```

This batch succeeds because the EXECUTE keyword is optional for the first proc `EXECUTE` in the batch, and the subsequent `EXECUTE` statement specifies the keyword.  This batch is not ambiguous with or without statement terminators:

```
myProc;
EXEC myProc;
```

This batch also succeeds because the EXECUTE keyword is optional for the first proc EXECUTE in the batch, and the subsequent EXECUTE statement specifies the keyword.  The T-SQL parser is lax enough here to recognize the EXEC introduces a new statement so the subsequent EXEC keyword and proc name are not interpreted as parameters to the first EXECUTE:

```
myProc
EXEC myProc
```

I'd like to add that the absence of semi-colon statement terminators is deprecated syntax.  I honestly don't expect semi-colons to become mandatory for quite some time.  In today's world, they are mandatory only when the next statement is a newly introduced T-SQL statement (e.g. WITH).

Comment: Maybe I miss something, but that does not quite answer my question of why they don't work together but executing alone works.

Comment: @Kenny, I added some more detail to may answer to better explain.  Note that a batch is a group of one or more statements submitted to SQL Server as a group.  The `EXECUTE` statement is mandatory only for subsequent statements on the same batch.  It is optional of the first or only statement.

Answer (score 4):

When a stored procedure name is referenced alone, i.e.

```
sp_who2
```

SQL Server will check this against commands it understands (i.e. procedures in current database, or shared procedures that are common from system databases). However this syntax permits multiple non-quoted words, such as:

```
sp_who2 active
```

In order to make the T-SQL language unambiguous, it's required that when you have multiple command verbs in a single batch, you need to separate them, for example with an EXEC or other suitable delimeter. Otherwise did you mean to pass the second command as a parameter to the first command, or did you mean literally two commands? SQL Server will permit the below, as you've made it clear:

```
sp_who2
EXEC sp_who2
```

That'll work fine. This will not though:

```
sp_who2
sp_who2
```

Because it's ambiguous as to whether you meant

```
 EXEC sp_who2 'sp_who2'
```

or

```
EXEC sp_who2
EXEC sp_who2
```

Other examples are statements like 'MERGE INTO' which require a semicolon or other terminator after any preceding statements in the batch, for the same reason - to avoid syntax ambiguity.

Comment: As noted in my question, SQL server does think that I am trying to pass an argument if I write _EXEC sp \sp_ when we do not have delimiter. That part I understand. What I wondered is the case well-delimited with _;_  as _EXEC sp; \sp;_. Why does it still fail in this case?

Comment: SQL Server permits exactly one 'naked' procedure call to be executed in each submitted batch of queries (i.e. A single EXEC can be omittted - even if it's preceded by SELECT, etc). This is documented in MSDN at ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx ) - but consider it an implementation detail in the grammar. This is because of the type of grammar lexer/parser being used to read the T-SQL commands from the input stream - and you'll find this kind of problem occurs in many areas of programming. I recommend the Wikipedia entries on LR/LALR/Recurisve descent parsing for more.